# dynamically populated name for module

Tags: angularjs

Is is possible to have that module name dynamically populated. I am trying to stay away from code duplication. Here is what I have:

app-categories.js;

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-categories", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "addNewTask"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

app-tasks.js:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-tasks", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute", "addNewTask"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

And now another controller 'addNewTaskController.js' that should be shared by many modules, in my case by 'app-categories' and 'app-tasks':

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    //angular.module("app-categories")
    angular.module("app-tasks")
    .controller("addNewTaskController", addNewTaskController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@estus suggestions were useful. I was able to still keep separate controllers as I originally have planned, and end up creating a common js file that will be shared by the two controllers, eliminating mentioned code duplication.

Here is how I have managed to do it:

addNewTaskControllerForAppCategoriesModule.js:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-categories")
    .controller("addNewTaskController", addNewTaskController);
})();
```

addNewTaskControllerForAppTasksModule:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-tasks")
    .controller("addNewTaskController", addNewTaskController);
})();
```

addNewTaskCommon.js:

```js
function addNewTaskController($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having this performed automatically for *all* modules should be avoided because it will cause more harm than good.

It is possible to create a common module for that

```
angular.module("app-common", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute", "addNewTask"]);
```

and load it instead.

It still shouldn't be included mechanically because some modules from `common` may cause side effects that will be undesirable when testing the modules separately.

Comment: So is that means that the function and the corresponding code inside of 'addNewTaskController' will be duplicated for 'app-tasks' and 'app-categories' in this case?

Comment: Modules are loaded only once. Notice that `common` module preferably shouldn't contain `config` and `run` blocks, these ones cause 'side effects' most often.

Comment: I appreciate your input, it helped, I upvoted your answer, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. To be clear, the question expects it to be `angular.module("app-common", [...]).controller("addNewTaskController", addNewTaskController)` and `angular.module("app-categories", ["app-common"])...` with no more `addNewTaskController` definitions. What you're doing in your question is overwriting `addNewTaskController` multiple times. This is highly undesirable and should be avoided. There can be only one unit with such name per app instance.